# Checkbox won't stay unchecked or vice versa

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I have looked many different solutions but almost all of them are not what I am trying to do.

I have an aspx page that has 5 checkboxes on it. I am pulling data from an SQL DB and setting the initial on/off state of the checkbox based on the retrieved value. This works fine.

The problem starts when I try to check or uncheck a checkbox. If it is checked it will uncheck for a split second and then the check returns or vice versa (unchecked to checked state).

Here are the checkboxes:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbIVPO" runat="server" Text=" Invoice Value & P.O.#" OnCheckedChanged="ckbIVPO_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbQuNotes" runat="server" Text=" Quality Notes" OnCheckedChanged="ckbQuNotes_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbShipTerms" runat="server" Text=" Ship To & Shipping Terms" OnCheckedChanged="ckbShipTerms_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbMatSurFin" runat="server" Text=" Material/Surface/Finish" OnCheckedChanged="ckbMatSurFin_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbFabFasExt" runat="server" Text=" Fabrication & Fastner Extras" OnCheckedChanged="ckbFabFasExt_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

The OnCheckedChange event for each one is basically the same (only control ID name changes):

```
If [control ID].Checked = checked Then
   [control ID].Checked = False
Else
    [Control ID].checked = True
End IF
```

I also found an article here on SO that talked about using hidden text boxes and setting the checkbox based on the value from it. But I can't seem to get that to work. I think I am missing something there.

Here is that code:

```
    If txbivpo.Text = "1" Then
        ckbIVPO.Checked = True
    Else
        ckbIVPO.Checked = False
    End If
    If txbshtrm.Text = "1" Then
        ckbShipTerms.Checked = True
    Else
        ckbShipTerms.Checked = False
    End If
    If txbqunotes.Text = "1" Then
        ckbQuNotes.Checked = True
    Else
        ckbQuNotes.Checked = False
    End If
    If txbmatsurfin.Text = "1" Then
        ckbMatSurFin.Checked = True
    Else
        ckbMatSurFin.Checked = False
    End If
    If txbfabfasext.Text = "1" Then
        ckbFabFasExt.Checked = True
    Else
        ckbFabFasExt.Checked = False
    End If
```

I just can't seem to get this to work. I am sure that I am missing something but I am not sure what it is. I am also not set in stone as to doing it this way. I am using VB because I am not very good with C#. (Actually I flat out suck at C#!) I am using the hidden text boxes to pull the data for the update query if the user changes something and I need to update the SQL.

Can anyone help me or point me to a clear example of how to simply have the check box change state, and stay, and then be able to update the hidden text box so the query will update correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess since the code for setting the correct textbox from the DB is not shown. But I think you have to wrap that piece of code in a IsPostBack check:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    setCheckBoxValuesFromDB
End If
```

What probably happens is when a checkbox is clicked a PostBack is performed. In that PostBack , presumably in Page_load, the default values are retrieved from the database and will overwrite the ones the user clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox initially unchecks because that is done browser-side. Once the postback is completed, the page is rendered again.

If you have not changed the data in the DB then you are going to get the state from the DB rendered.

Presumably you have a method to initialize the checkboxes, let us call it `InitCheckboxes`, and you call it in a Page_Load method. All you need to do is *not* call that method on postbacks, like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (Page.IsPostBack) Then
        InitCheckboxes()
    End If
End Sub
```